# Variables outside switch cases java

Tags: java, string, variables, console, switch-statement

I'm trying to print out different variables I've already declared in different switch cases, they're all in one switch block in a for loop but the compiler isn't allowing me use the variables. Giving me a "cannot find symbol" error.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double hammer = 3.25, nails = 5.25, paint = 4.75, paintBrush = 2.25, balance = 50.00;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Local Hardware Point of Sales");
    System.out.println("\t::MENU::");
    System.out.println("1. Purchase Items\n2. Display current purchases\n3. Display account balance\n4. Complete transactions and Exit");
    System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    switch(choice){

        case 1: 
                     for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){      
            System.out.println("\n\tPurchase Items");
            System.out.println("What items would you like to purchase?");
            System.out.println("\tItems \t\tPrices");
            System.out.println("\tHammer\t\t-$3.25\n\tNails\t\t-$3.25\n\tPaint\t\t-$3.25\n\tPaint Brush\t-$3.25");
            String item = input.next(); 
    switch (item) {
        case "Hammer":
        case "hammer":
            System.out.println("How many Hammers would you like to purchase?");
            int hItem = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Starting Balance: $" + balance);
            double hPrice = hItem*hammer;
            System.out.println("Cost for " + hItem + " Hammers: $" + hPrice);
            double hBalance = balance - hPrice;
            System.out.println("Final Balance: $" + hBalance);
            if(hBalance > 50.00){
                System.out.println("WARNING: YOU HAVE INSUFFICIENT FUNDS FOR THIS PURCHASE. YOU CANNOT PURCHASE 30 NAILS.");
                System.out.println("You will be returned to the main menu...");  
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\nPurchase the "+ hItem+ " Hammers (Y/N)");
                String ch = input.next();
                if(ch.equals("Yes") || (ch.equals("Y")) || (ch.equals("y")) ){
                    System.out.println("You purchased "+hItem+"Hammers for "+ hPrice);   
                }

            }
            break;

        case "Nails":
        case "nails":
            System.out.println("How many Nails would you like to purchase?");
            int nItem = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Starting Balance: $" + balance);
            double nPrice = nItem*nails;
            System.out.println("Cost for " + nItem + " Nails: $" + nPrice);
            double nBalance = balance - nPrice;
            System.out.println("Final Balance: $" + nBalance);
            if(nBalance > 50.00){
                System.out.println("WARNING: YOU HAVE INSUFFICIENT FUNDS FOR THIS PURCHASE. YOU CANNOT PURCHASE 30 NAILS.");
                System.out.println("You will be returned to the main menu...");  
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\nPurchase the "+ nItem+ " Nails (Y/N)");
                String ch = input.next();
                if(ch.equals("Yes") || (ch.equals("Y")) || (ch.equals("y")) ){
                System.out.println("You purchased "+nItem+" Nails for "+ nPrice);   
                }  
            }
            break;

        case "Paint":
        case "paint":
            System.out.println("How many Paints would you like to purchase?");
            int pItem = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Starting Balance: $" + balance);
            double pPrice = pItem*nails;
            System.out.println("Cost for " + pItem + " Paints: $" + pPrice);
            double pBalance = balance - pPrice;
            System.out.println("Final Balance: $" + pBalance);
            if(pBalance > 50.00){
                System.out.println("WARNING: YOU HAVE INSUFFICIENT FUNDS FOR THIS PURCHASE. YOU CANNOT PURCHASE 30 NAILS.");
                System.out.println("You will be returned to the main menu...");  
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\nPurchase the "+ pItem+ " Paints (Y/N)");
                String ch = input.next();
                if(ch.equals("Yes") || (ch.equals("Y")) || (ch.equals("y")) ){
                System.out.println("You purchased "+pItem+" Paints for "+ pPrice);   
                }  
            }
            break;

        case "Paint Brush":
        case "paint brush":
            System.out.println("How many Paint Brushes would you like to purchase?");
            int pbItem = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Starting Balance: $" + balance);
            double pbPrice = pbItem*nails;
            System.out.println("Cost for " + pbItem + " Paint Brushes: $" + pbPrice);
            double pbBalance = balance - pbPrice;
            System.out.println("Final Balance: $" + pbBalance);
            if(pbBalance > 50.00){
                System.out.println("WARNING: YOU HAVE INSUFFICIENT FUNDS FOR THIS PURCHASE. YOU CANNOT PURCHASE 30 NAILS.");
                System.out.println("You will be returned to the main menu...");  
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\nPurchase the "+ pbItem+ " Paint Brushes (Y/N)");
                String ch = input.next();
                if(ch.equals("Yes") || (ch.equals("Y")) || (ch.equals("y")) ){
                 System.out.println("You purchased "+pbItem+" Paint Brushes for "+ pbPrice);   
                }  
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("\nMake another purchase? (Y/N)");
      String ans = input.next();
      if(ans.equals("n"))
          System.out.println("\tCurrent Receipt");
      System.out.println("Items \t\tQuantity \t\tPrice Per \t\tTotal Price");
      System.out.println("Hammer \t\t"+**hItem**+" \t\t\t"+hammer+" \t\t\t"+**hPrice**);
      System.out.println("Nails \t\t"+**nItem**+" \t\t\t"+nails+" \t\t\t"+**nPrice**);
      System.out.println("Paint \t\t"+**pItem**+" \t\t\t"+paint+" \t\t\t"+**pPrice**);
      System.out.println("Paint Brush \t\t"+**pbItem**+" \t\t\t"+paintBrush+" \t\t\t"+**pbPrice**);
     }
    }
}
```

}

I bolded the variables that are giving the error. P.s I am not allowed to use methods for this project, strictly conditional statements and loops.

Also if anyone doesn't mind, I'm trying to get string input for "Paint Brush" but using input.next() has issues with the space, and when I used input.nexLine() it completely ignored the input and ended the program, so had to revert back to next().

Please if anyone can help, much appreciated. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variables that give you an error outside of the switch-case. Currently their *scope* is limited to only the inside of the `case` part, meaning that for the rest of the code (outside of the `case`) they don't exist.

Comment: thanks that helped for the options. Now my problem is transferring the same values from case 1 to case 2.

Comment: @ElizabethEkefre Looks like you need a loop there. Create the variables outside the `while` loop, then the will be available for each command.